# Clang-tidy warning for static std::stringstream

Tags: c++, stringstream, clang-tidy

I have the following MCVE:

```
#include <sstream>

struct A {
    static std::stringstream s;
};

std::stringstream A::s;

int main() {}
```

When I run clang-tidy 6.0.1 on this code I get the following warning:

```
static_sstream.cpp:7:22: warning: initializing non-local variable with non-const expression depending on uninitialized non-local variable 'out' [cppcoreguidelines-interfaces-global-init]
std::stringstream A::s;
                     ^
```

It seems that the problem lies in the fact that the constructor of `std::stringstream` has a parameter with the default value of `std::ios_base::out`. My question is, is this a real problem? And if so, what is the correct way of using a static `std::stringstream` in a class?

Comment: This looks like a QoI issue. Those flags are declared `constexpr` https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/ios_base/openmode. I think Clang-tidy has a bug.

Comment: I just found [`static constexpr openmode out = /*implementation defined*/`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/ios_base/openmode). Shouldn't the `constexpr` grant "compile-time" initialization of `out` or did I mis-understand the concept?

Comment: Interestingly, I have looked into the header files of both libstdc++ and libc++ (recent versions) and they are both missing the `constexpr` specifier, they only use `const`.

Answer (score 0):

MSVC 2015(windows) compiles the above code snippet without any warnings. Verified the headers and it has constexpr. Looks like an issue with Clang-tidy.

Comment: It is, in fact, not an issue with clang-tidy, it is an issue of the standard library headers of both libc++ and libstdc++, see the comments above.